# What kind of disk operation is not read or write?

Tags: charts, storage, io

When reading a performance chart like this, what does the **Other IO/Sec** mean? What kind of operation is not read or write?

[image: performance chart]

The info button only leads to a doc with this vague description:

> - NFS Write – When selected, displays NFS write Input/Output       operations per second.
> - NFS Read – When selected, displays NFS read    Input/Output    operations per second.
> - NFS Other – When selected,    displays NFS other Input/Output    operations per second.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what those things are measuring.

It is possible that from a network filesystem perspective traversing a directory does not count as a *file* read or write operation, or that read or write operations only count on actual disk access and operating system cache hits are not counted. The first read to get a directory listing might hit the disk, but subsequent scans hit the cache in either the OS or the network filesystem stack.

There are also some level of overheads in network "keep this connection alive", "acknowledge" packets and "send me the next one" that could be counted amongst "other" I/O.

Comment: Thanks, Mokubai. The cache theory seem very plausible. Mainly because of the moment right before 10 o'clock where the cache would be flushed somehow and right after this the NFS Read IO goes up really fast, meaning all data was being read from disk again. I'm gonna try to find any log on my system that confirms that hypotheses.

Answer (score 1):

There are many other I/O requests to a file-system besides read and write.

Some examples:

- flush : write buffer data to the physical file
- seek : position file to a given offset
- open file
- close file
- resize file
- etc.

Comment: Thanks, harrymc. From those options I believe only the **flush** could cause such high values as we can see on the chart, right?

Comment: There's a good chance that it is caused by flush (or sync).